# Remove resize cursor from Window component in GXT

Tags: java, gwt, extjs, gxt

The Window component that I use has Resizable flag set to false but the resize cursor on the edges still appear. Is there any way to change the cursor to normal ?

I am using Sencha GXT 3, with appearance pattern.

**EDIT:**

Both answers (SSR and Jonathan) are correct but a bit overkill. And what happens to other Windows which are resizable ?

I notified Sencha about the issue and they labeled it as a bug. **Upgrading to GXT 3.0.3+** will solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be not be possible without hacking into gxt code. The resize cursor code seems to be hardcoded into css styles in gwt code which is obfuscated. You can see in the below image a obfuscated style with **cursor : e-resize**;

[image]

1. Open up gxt jar. Copy the relevant Window code into your code base in same package structure as gxt and then make the changes in gwt template style related to Window. Ensure this class is in higher classpath hierarchy than gxt code when gwt compiler picks it up.
2. Log a bug with GXT team to get a official patch.

Answer (score 0):

The `Resizable` class has `ResizableAppearance`. If we look in `ResizableBaseAppearance`, we can take a look at how the GXT team has implemented this stuff.

I'm guessing that what is going on is that when a `Window` is initially created, `Window.setResizable(true)` is called which injects the styles and sets up the handlers for resizing.

You could roll your own `ResizeableAppearance` and set up your deferred-binding rules to use yours instead of the default `ResizableBaseAppearance` (make sure those rules come after your inherit of GXT in your `*.gwt.xml`).

This will replace the appearance of the `Resizer` in ALL `Window`s. So, the trick would be to figure out how to determine if resizing is turned off or not.

Hope this helps.